# No operations defined in spec! while specifying multiple paths in swagger ui and springfox

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I want to display two REST API endpoints in Swagger ui: /cart and /post.

When I specify either /cart or /post works fine but with both showing me error as

> No operations defined in spec!

in swagger-ui

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/cart"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/post"))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Is this Springfox or some other framework?

Comment: no it is springfox

Comment: return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()

                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(("com.valens.compony")))

                .paths(Predicates.or( PathSelectors.regex("/cart"),PathSelectors.regex("/post")))

                .build()

                .pathMapping("/")


i found this solution but it only works in java not in scala

Comment: Verify the endpoint root path.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use ***.paths(PathSelectors.any())*** instead of ***.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/cart"))*** and ***.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/post"))***

Answer (score 1):

With Spring boot `2.6.x` you also need:

```yaml
spring:  
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

Answer (score 0):

It because you use `AND` condition

```
  public ApiSelectorBuilder paths(Predicate<String> selector) {
    pathSelector = pathSelector.and(selector);
    return this;
  }
```

you can combine conditions by using `OR` clause

```
.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/cart").or(PathSelectors.ant("/post")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add package xxxx as root package so It can scan swagger config in all class

```
public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                    return swaggerPath;
                }
            }).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("xxxx")).build()
                    .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securitySchema()))
                    .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext())).apiInfo(metaData());
```

Answer (score 0):

this the solution : is add the the path where exactly you have the controllers classe

exemple :
"org.zaid.aitfriha.controller.api" is the path where exactly you have controllers

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.zaid.aitfriha.controller.api"))
```

dont use org.zaid.* or org.zaid.aitfriha.* or org.zaid.aitfriha.controller.*

Be careful with  "/api/AbsenceRequest" dont works it must be "/api/absenceRequest"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/absenceRequest")
@CrossOrigin("*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the base package to the RequestHandlerSelectors object in your Swagger Config class. You can point to the specific package where you have your OpenAPI annotations added, i.e. "controller", or just leave it pointing to the root, spring will scan all the nested packages.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build().apiInfo(apiInfoMetaData());
}
```